# Directions from current location to poi android maps v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i reading lots of thread here in SO but i wasn't able to fix my problem.

I built a simple app that show a number of poi, info views and I was able to draw a polyline and have the walking directions in the map properly, setting two Lat Lng  point.

Right now i'm trying to add the function that the START POINT as the current location of the user. If i use the map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); it shows the blu point of my position, and i used the "getMyLocation().getLatitude();" and "getMyLocation().getLongitude();" methods to take correct coordinate. But when i run my app, it crashes with a NullPoint error.

**EDIT: i solved my problem, i edited the MainAcrivity class with the solution**

This is my MainActivity.java

```
    package com.directions.android;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.directions.route.Route;
import com.directions.route.Routing;
import com.directions.route.RoutingListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements RoutingListener {
    protected GoogleMap map;
    protected LatLng start;
    protected LatLng end;
    protected Double myPosLat;
    protected double myPosLng;
    /**
     * This activity loads a map and then displays the route and pushpins on it.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = fm.getMap();

        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(47.3369217,9.353883));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);

        map.moveCamera(center);
        map.animateCamera(zoom);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("You are here!"));

            start = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            end = new LatLng(44.48861858, 11.36779726);

            Routing routing = new Routing(Routing.TravelMode.WALKING);
            routing.registerListener(MyActivity.this);
            routing.execute(start, end);
        }
    });




    }


    @Override
    public void onRoutingFailure() {
        // The Routing request failed
    }

    @Override
    public void onRoutingStart() {
        // The Routing Request starts
    }

    @Override
    public void onRoutingSuccess(PolylineOptions mPolyOptions, Route route) {
        PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polyOptions.color(Color.RED);
        polyOptions.width(8);
        polyOptions.addAll(mPolyOptions.getPoints());
        map.addPolyline(polyOptions);

        // Start marker
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(start);
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue));
        map.addMarker(options);

        // End marker
        options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(end);
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green));
        map.addMarker(options);


    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your LogCat logs.

Comment: Without logcat we can`t predict your problem:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what i was asking. This is the snippet of code to add a route from current location to a fixed Lat Long.

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                        location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("You are here!"));

                start = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                end = new LatLng(44.48861858, 11.36779726);

                Routing routing = new Routing(Routing.TravelMode.WALKING);
                routing.registerListener(MyActivity.this);
                routing.execute(start, end);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you put the part of your code related to `map.getMyLocation()` in a `OnMyLocationChangeListener`. Getting `MyLocation` takes time on Android.

```
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

            myPosLat = location.getLatitude();
            myPosLng = location.getLongitude();

            start = new LatLng(myPosLat, myPosLng);
            end = new LatLng(48.823515, 10.1246599);

            Routing routing = new Routing(Routing.TravelMode.WALKING);
            routing.registerListener(this);
            routing.execute(start, end);

        }
    });
```